# image not showing after saving in WPF

Tags: wpf, image

i am trying to save project icon and after saving i need to show on the next page, but it doesn't show . Each time i need to include that image in project first, then rebuild the project then it become visible.
i am using following code.please tell me where i am doing wrong and **i want image that i newly saved will be automatically included in the project**

```
string imagename = imagebind1.Source.ToString();
int indxofslash = imagename.LastIndexOf('/');
string substribgimgname = imagename.Substring(indxofslash + 1).ToString();
string imagename1 = "/img/icons/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imagename);
String appStartPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
string folderpath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + "\\img\\icons\\";
if (!Directory.Exists(folderpath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
}
string filePath = folderpath + substribgimgname;
string localPath = new Uri(imagename).LocalPath;

System.IO.File.Copy(localPath, filePath, true);
```

Comment: You cannot include an image you saved at runtime in your project. You can however load any image on disk and show it. If that fails, maybe you can post the code that does this and get help on it.

Comment: is the image created or associated at runtime? is it user image or user selects it? correect me if I am wrong, you may want to copy the user selected image to some folder and display on your application's page.

Comment: @Pushpraj Ruhal,  i am uploading an image from local PC and save image path in database and image  in Server Folder. so when i try to bind that image , i is not becoming visible, what i have noticed that, image remain excluded from project , first i need to include it in project and need to run again by rebuilding project

Comment: is it wpf? wpf tends to be desktop application. or is it a client server application?

Comment: yes its in WPF, and Desktop App